# Do I need internet connection to use ppa ondrej?

Tags: server, ppa, playonlinux, php7

I want to use ondrej ppa to upgrade php version in ubuntu server. Do I need internet connection to run this command?

```
  sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
```

I had tried and produce error of ondrej/ubuntu/php, ondrej user or team does not exist.

Thank  you

Comment: Yes you do because it needs to communicate with the ppa and download the key file to activate it so that you can install the PHP, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An internet connection is required when adding a PPA so the key file can be downloaded, then installed. Then the PPA is activated.  After the PPA is active, you can download and install the PHP version you want.

Hope this helps!